# Alternatives to "Sleep in the bed you made"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I seem to recall one having something to do with the "hole you dug" but maybe I made that up.

Either way, I'm interested in any other expressions of this form. And to clarify the expression means basically to deal with the situation you have created for yourself.

Comment: The way I've generally heard it is "You made your bed, now sleep in it."

Comment: Related questions that may be helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175010/how-to-say-you-have-this-much-work-to-do-because-you-decided-to-do-that-much-m/175237#175237 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189078/a-frankensteins-monster-similar-metaphors/189079#189079

Comment: ***You've made your bed (and you'll have to lie in it).  also You made your bed (now lie in it).*** : 
something that you say in order to tell someone that they must accept that they will suffer as a result of something bad that they have done. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You've+made+your+bed

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Yeah, that's probably more common.

Comment: Ooops, stupid typo... I meant to say "You've made your bed, now lie in it". lol!

Comment: "Eating crow" is similar but specific to strong opinions.  You can also, more mildly,  "paint yourself into a corner."

Answer (score 4):

There must be a few sayings which convey what you mean.  Three come to  mind but **the first one seems to fit best:**

**"you reap what you sow"**, which means...

> - "everything that happens to you is a result of your own actions" ([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+reap+what+you+sow))

**"get a taste of your own medicine"** It's also the title of a [novel](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=8rY7PQAACAAJ&dq=a+taste+of+your+own+medicine&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAmoVChMI06LakqeTyAIVSCKQCh3RAAYy) which became [a movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101746/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) and means...

> - a sample of the unpleasantness that one has been giving other people. ([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+taste+of+own+medicine))

and **"hoist with his own petard"** which means...

> - "to be harmed by one's own plan to harm someone else" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petard#.22Hoist_with_his_own_petard.22))

Answer (score 2):

I've heard "You dug your grave, you can lie in it" before.   Kinda grim but similar.

Just a much longer sleep.  :)

Answer (score 2):

In Texas, when I was growing up, a somewhat relevant expression was surprisingly popular:

> Dance with the one that brung you.

The scenario imagined by this phrase is that you've been invited to a dance by one particular person, but now that you're there you're tempted to dance with other people.

The quotation was originally made famous (I believe) by University of Texas football coach Darrell Royal, who was asked whether, for a bowl game at the end of the season, he might open up his team's heavily run-oriented offense by throwing more passes. His answer, to the effect that "I've always believed that you should dance with the one that brung you," was taken to mean that the team had gotten to the bowl game by running the ball on offense, so it should continue that orientation at the bowl game instead of trying something different.

But in much the same sense that its successful running game was the thing that "brung" the Longhorns to the bowl game, that running game was the bed that the team had been making all season long—and now, in the bowl game, for good or for ill, the team was going to lie in it.

Answer (score 0):

"Eating your own dog food" comes to mind

Comment: I've never heard this: do you have a reference for it?

Comment: I've never heard of it before, but apparently it's a term used to describe when a company uses it's own product to test and promote the product, and not the same as the idiom that OP is referring to. More info on the "eating your own dog food" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food

Comment: Interesting, but completely different.

Comment: @Centaurus No problem; glad to help.